# How is the volume of this pyramid obvious?

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

The corner of a unit cube is chopped off such that the cut runs through the three vertices adjacent to the vertex of the chosen corner. The chopped of part is a pyramid. The source says the volume of the pyramid is obviously $\frac16$. I don't understand how this is obvious. Can someone help me visualize this?
I don't want a proper proof because I can also do that ie find the area of base and height and volume is $\frac13$ × base area × height.

I want someone to help me visualize the result as to why this is obvious that the volume of the chopped off pyramid is $\frac16$th of the volume of the cube.

Comment: Ok so I’ve tried cutting up a cube hoping to get six such pyramids and that doesn’t work. I’m trying something else now.

Comment: If you cut off four of these corners from a unit cube you are left with a regular tetrahedron with side length $\sqrt 2$. You plug that into some formula and get the volume of $\frac{(\sqrt2)^3}{6\sqrt 2}=\frac 26.$ That leaves $\frac46$ for the four pyramids. Ie $\frac 16$ each. But this isn’t obvious at all. I had to sketch this and then I cut up a physical cube just to make sure.

Comment: How obvious it is depends on what you know about pyramids. For example, if you know how to apply the formula $\frac13bh$ to find the volume, you just plug in values.

Comment: @idpd15 If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

The $\sim$ symbols indicate equivalences in volume due to Cavalieri's principle. The $\cong$ symbols indicate congruences; the solids in the bottom row are the chopped-off pyramids of the question. Thus half a cube has the volume of three such pyramids, and the full cube has the volume of six.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the cube orthogonally along the diagonal of the top horizontal face. You get two equal prisms having the same base and the same height of the pyramid, so its volume is one third of the volume of the prism which is half the cube, so the pyramid is one sixth of the cube.

Hope it is useful